# Are there any ways to improve the developer experience of writing a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins

I've been following a few tutorials to get started with Jenkins, and they all describe the same workflow:

1. Write a Jenkinsfile
2. Add it to SCM
3. Add the project to Jenkins via the Web UI
4. Trigger a build in Jenkins
5. Modify the Jenkinsfile
6. Commit changes
7. `goto 4`

Is this really the only way to develop a Jenkinsfile? It's a terrible developer experience.

Does Jenkins include any developer conveniences, like the ability to watch a Jenkinsfile and trigger builds automatically, without using SCM?

Are there any other tools out there to improve the developer experience of writing Jenkinsfiles?

Comment: For added "fun", have a Jenkins build that runs integration tests that take 45 minutes to run.

Comment: You can configure your SCM configuration to trigger on every commit or poll very frequently. I think that you can also directly write your jenkinsfile through the UI. So you can temporarily develop on the UI and when it's OK, put it in your SCM

Answer (score 1):

With jenkins you can automate the execution of a job or Pipeline with:

- [jenkins-cli.jar](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/) command line tool
- [REST API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

You can also install plugins to configure hooks on your SCM server and automate the Pipeline or Jenkins job execution on every commit event.

- If using github you can use the [GitHub plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github)

If you want to skip the adding project via the web UI, you can consider to automate the project creation by using:

- [multibranch pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/) that way every branch of a repo will be scanned in order to find a Jenkinsfile and if it is found it will be parsed and the project will be created
- Use [job dsl](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob) to automate the Pipeline project creation.